# Is there a New Testament parallel to cities of refuge?

Tags: numbers, typology

Many things in the Old Testament have a New Testament parallel. For example, the OT has animal sacrifices. In the NT, Jesus is described as the Lamb of God, sacrificed for sins.

My question: I find cities of refuge mentioned in Numbers 35. Have published commentators found any NT spiritual parallel to this idea?

Comment: Nice question.  I gave it a small edit to make it on topic ("published commentaries" instead of "you" - we generally aren't interested in the opinions of individual believers here).

Answer (score 5):

Yes.

> **Hebrews 6:16** (KJV)
>   That by two immutable things, in which it was impossible for God to lie, we might have a strong consolation, who have fled for refuge to lay hold upon the hope set before us:

[Matthew Henry's commentary](https://www.blueletterbible.org/Comm/mhc/Hbr/Hbr_006.cfm) on this verse points to Jesus as our present refuge:

> They are such as have fled for refuge to the hope set before them.
>   Under the law there were cities of refuge provided for those who were
>   pursued by the avenger of blood. Here is a much better refuge prepared
>   by the gospel, a refuge for all sinners who shall have the heart to
>   flee to it; yea, though they have been the chief of sinners.